# 'Reporter output' is empty in testng report

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, testng, test-reporting

I'm trying to add screenshots on fail to testng report.
I'm running it according to this tutorial: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-reporters-asserts/

My function

```
public static void onTestFailure(ITestContext tc, ITestResult result, WebDriver driver) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy_hh_mm_ss");
    String methodName = result.getName();
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        String reportDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath() + "\\test-output\\" +tc.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getName();
        System.out.printf(reportDirectory);
        File destFile = new File((String) reportDirectory+"\\failure_screenshots\\"+methodName+"_"+formater.format(calendar.getTime())+".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destFile);
        Reporter.log("<a href='"+ destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "'> <img src='"+ destFile.getAbsolutePath() + "' height='100' width='100'/> </a>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is ttht screenshot appears in proper place, but link from Reporter.log never gets to 'Reporter output' view.

Does anybody know what I need to do to make it work?

It's Java project with maven

Comment: where is this method invoked : after @ Test annotated method or in any @ afterTest annotated method ?

Comment: It's in @AfterMethod annotated method, i have there  if(result.FAILURE == result.getStatus()) and then invokes screenshot and logging link

Comment: Reporter.logs only work inside  @_Test annotated methods. To add custom logs into the report you need to implement listeners. Checkout the code snippets below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use listeners for this purpose. Create a new class of a given name and extend TestListenerAdapter. Override the onTestFailure method. Write your screenshot capture code here.

```
public class ListenersEvents extends TestListenerAdapter  {
    @Override
        public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
            Object currentClass = result.getInstance();
            WebDriver webDriver = ((browserSetup) currentClass).getActiveObject();


            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                      Reporter.log("Test Result: FAIL",true);
                    takeScreenshotOfFailureFromLocalMachine(result,webDriver);

                } else {
                    Reporter.log("Test Result: PASS",true);
                }
        }


}
```

The only tricky part is how you will be passing the driver object reference to the listener class. 
So I added a getter method in the class where the driver is instantiated ,for getting active driver object.

```
    public class browserSetup{
       WebDriver driver;

        public WebDriver createFirefoxDriver(){
// set path for geckodriver
         return new FirefoxDriver();
         }
public WebDriver createChromeDriver(){
//set path for chrome driver
         return new ChromeDriver();
         }

        public WebDriver getActiveObject() {
                return this.driver;
            }
    }
```